# enumerate the logical drives for a perticule physical device name

Tags: windows, winapi, hard-drive

Is there any way to enumerate all logical drives residing on a physical device ? 
For example. C:\ is the system drive resides on a physical disk, How can I enumerate other drives residing on same physical disk.

Thanks,

Comment: [Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394175.aspx) along with [Win32_DiskPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135.aspx).

Comment: I need solution using Win32 API

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286532/conversion-of-physical-drive-paths-using-c) shows an example of a similar thing using WMI from C++. It's not for the faint-hearted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a peek at the source code of AlphaFS: https://alphafs.codeplex.com/

It contains a Volume/VolumeInfo class that enumerates logical drives on volumes.